# Show personalized banner exhibits on Ubuntu Software Center

Tags: software-center, python

How can I show my own personalized banner exhibits on Ubuntu Software Center?

I've seen some URL definitions on `/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/enums.py` and `/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/distro/Ubuntu.py` so far.

I also tried to track the code from the views to the core. But I got lost. `_append_banner_adds` calls `SoftwareCenterAgent`. It calls `SpawnHelper`. Then I get lost. There are also some calls at `SimpleFileDownloader` but I'm not able to track them.

Also, I've noticed this entry on the debug log.

```
2013-02-08 15:07:43,731 - softwarecenter.simplefiledownloader - DEBUG - download_file: http://software-center.ubuntu.com/site_media/exhibits/2012/12/SC_banner_Mixxx_2.png None True
```

Is there documentation on how this is implemented? Some simple recipe to change the default banners and put my own banners on a clean way would be very helpful.

I suppose I can simply rewrite the `_append_banner_adds` function, but I'm not very prolific on python and I'd like to understand and use the same methods Ubuntu is using, if possible.

Answer (score 6):

Open up `/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/backend/scagent.py` and edit the beginning of this function, so that it says:

```
def query_exhibits(self):
    import urllib, json
    class Obj:
      def __init__(self, obj):
        self.obj = obj
      def __getattr__(self, name):
        if name[:2] == "__": return object.__getattr__(self, name)
        return self.obj[name]

    self.emit("exhibits", [Obj(x) for x in json.loads(urllib.urlopen("http://localhost:8800/cgi-bin/bannerlist.py").read())])
    return
```

You can leave the rest as it is, it will never be reached.

If you want scripting support in your `<iframe>`, edit

`/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/widgets/exhibits.py`

and find `settings.set_property("enable-scripts", False)`. Change `False` to `True`.

Now make `/var/www/cgi-bin/bannerlist.py` and make it executable:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import json

print("Content-type: application/json\n")

print(json.dumps([
{
  "html": "<iframe src='file:/tmp/test.html'></iframe>",
  "title_translated": "Hey dawg",
  "click_url": "http://4chan.org",
  "package_names": ("gimp"),
  "banner_urls": ["file:/"],
  "published": True
},
{
  "html": "<iframe src='http://localhost:8800/cgi-bin/banner.py'></iframe>",
  "title_translated": "Hey dawg",
  "click_url": "http://4chan.org",
  "package_names": ("gimp"),
  "banner_urls": ["file:/"],
  "published": True
}
]))
```

This demonstrates a generated banner list.

Now make `/var/www/cgi-bin/banner.py` and make it executable:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import time
print("Content-type: image/svg+xml\n")
print("""
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <rect width="300" height="100"
  style="fill:rgba(0,0,255,0.5);stroke-width:1;stroke:rgba(0,0,0,0.5)"/>
  <text x="0" y="25" fill="black">Time is """ + str(time.time()) + """</text>
</svg> 
""")
```

This demonstrates a generated banner.

You might need to clear the software-center cache. You can do that using `rm -rf ~/.cache/software-center`.

Obviously you need to put something in `/tmp/test.html` for the first banner to work.

You also need a webserver running at 8800 with a `cgi-bin` for this to work. If you don't have this, run this in Bash:

```
cd /var/www
python -c "import BaseHTTPServer as h, CGIHTTPServer as c;
i = c.CGIHTTPRequestHandler;
i.cgi_directories = ['/cgi-bin'];
h.HTTPServer(('', 8800),i).serve_forever()"
```

You need to style the `iframe` to make it fill the space, but you figured that out.

Comment: Thanks! Can't I reuse the standard banner rotator? I tried declaring multiple classes and it worked pretty well. I'm having some styling issues with the iframe, but I should be able to sort that out. Now I want to gather the banner exhibits from a web server, so I should probably use JSON. Please notice that the bounty includes this, gathering the banners from my own server. If you include this information, I'll be able to award you the bounty :)

Comment: @JorgeSuárezdeLis: done

Comment: Ok, this isn't working. On the application I see an error like this: `Unable to load page - Problem occurred while loading the URL http:localhost:8800cgi-binbanner.py` (the same for the local version on `/tmp`). The old version worked, but now it seems to strip the URLs slashes somewhere. The exhibits are gathered OK, and I can print the HTML contents into the console and the slashes are there, but on the application they're missing! What could be happening?

Comment: Well, are you sure the URL is accessible? Try loading it using `curl` in the console. I think it only strips the slashes in the error message.

Comment: I don't think so. [I've taken an screenshot](http://s9.postimage.org/v969ihzov/Captura_de_pantalla_de_2013_02_18_21_08_41.png). The two first petitions are from Firefox. Only the bannerlist seems to be gathered from the software center.

Comment: Did you try clearing the cache? Maybe the error page was cached. There is only one request for banner.py in the web server log. This suggests that software-center gave up on it earlier and cached the error.

Comment: I've just deleted `.cache/software-center` and the problem remains. But unfortunately, I tried again your old answer and it's not working either! I've deleted `/usr/share/software-center`, reinstalled software-center, and reapplied the changes carefully and the problem remains. Using 12.04 btw, someone removed the tag. Everything went straightforward except for the `banner_urls` property, as it seems to be `banner_url` on 12.04. Some ideas?

Comment: Beware that `/tmp` is emptied at least every time you reboot. The old version was dependent on the file there, but of course if you change the path you can store it anywhere readable.

Comment: I'm aware of that. That's not the problem, unfortunately :(

Comment: OK, tried on new virtual machines. this is working OK for 12.10, but not for 12.04. I'll try to find out why, but for now I'll grant you the bounty. Thank you for your patience.